# Multiple Inheritance, copy constructor, and base class initialization?

Tags: c++, constructor, multiple-inheritance, copy-constructor

How do I write a copy constructor with Multiple Inheritance?

`B1` and `B2` is inherited by `D` there is no diamond in inheritance chain. I need to write a copy constructor in `D` such that it calls copy constructors of `B1` and `B2`

I want to avoid writing a `clone()` here

Comment: Why would you even *write* such a copy constructor?

Answer (score 6):

What's wrong with the classical approach:

```
D(const D& other) : B1(other), B2(other)
{
}
```

?

Comment: Thanks I thought That will not work. actually I was stuck in some other place. and thought that is the problem

Comment: @DiproSen - as long as none of the bases is virtual this works fine. Virtual bases, however, are initialized from the constructor for the most derived type. Same syntax, but you have to put it into every derived type that might be instantiated.

Comment: @PeteBecker Wow, how do I send flowers to you? Hours of debugging fixed in a minute. Thanks a lot!